# LOCAL INFILE ERROR: but as of v2.0 you must provide streamFactory option returning ReadStream

Tags: load-data-infile, sqltools

I wanted to upload a csv file using SQL commands but I got this error.

> As a result of LOCAL INFILE command server wants to read yob2019.csv file, but as of v2.0 you must provide streamFactory option returning ReadStream.

I am working in VScode envoronment with mysql version 8.2.0.

Here is my sql

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'yob2019.csv'  INTO TABLE baby_names  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

I have tried refrencing [here](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1080) but couldn't fix it.